# Looping javascript function on time intervals

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop, effect

I a script, in JavaScript, that makes a typewriting effect. I've tried to loop it, so that it executes in a loop after 10 seconds from the end of execution. In other words there is a typewriting effect and when the text is written after ten second code will execute once again. I've tried with `setTimeout()`, however it did not work.

Thanks for help in advance.

```
function setupTypewriter(t) {
  var HTML = t.innerHTML;

  t.innerHTML = "";

  var cursorPosition = 0,
      tag = "",
      writingTag = false,
      tagOpen = false,
      typeSpeed = 50,
      tempTypeSpeed = 0;

  var type = function() {

    if (writingTag === true) {
      tag += HTML[cursorPosition];
    }

    if (HTML[cursorPosition] === "<") {
      tempTypeSpeed = 0;
      if (tagOpen) {
        tagOpen = false;
        writingTag = true;
      } else {
        tag = "";
        tagOpen = true;
        writingTag = true;
        tag += HTML[cursorPosition];
      }
    }
    if (!writingTag && tagOpen) {
      tag.innerHTML += HTML[cursorPosition];
    }
    if (!writingTag && !tagOpen) {
      if (HTML[cursorPosition] === " ") {
        tempTypeSpeed = 0;
      }
      else {
        tempTypeSpeed = (Math.random() * typeSpeed) + 50;
      }
      t.innerHTML += HTML[cursorPosition];
    }
    if (writingTag === true && HTML[cursorPosition] === ">") {
      tempTypeSpeed = (Math.random() * typeSpeed) + 50;
      writingTag = false;
      if (tagOpen) {
        var newSpan = document.createElement("span");
        t.appendChild(newSpan);
        newSpan.innerHTML = tag;
        tag = newSpan.firstChild;
      }
    }

    cursorPosition += 1;
    if (cursorPosition < HTML.length - 1) {
      setTimeout(type, tempTypeSpeed);
    }

  };

  return {
    type: type
  };
}

var typer = document.getElementById('typewriter');

typewriter = setupTypewriter(typewriter);

typewriter.type();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want setInterval.

setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);

This code will run every three seconds.

Full documentation, examples etc. here (including how to stop it):

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: thanks for sharing. I have seen that, however I am not sure how to use this with my function. JS is a liitle new for me (I use C# normally). As You can see at the bottom there are three lines of code and without them the typewriting effect does not work. When I use the code like that var myVar;

function myFunction() {
    myVar = setInterval(setupTypewriter, 3000);
} the function executes onces (only once the effect is displayed) and that's it. Nothing more happens.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> typewriter = setupTypewriter(typewriter);
> ```

You pass `typewriter` variable to `setupTypewriter`, but it doesn't exist yet. Here you want to use

```
typewriter = setupTypewriter(typer);
```

---

BTW, I can't understand how you print tags. You print `<`, `d`, `i`, `v`, `>` with zero delay, but the parser still may break. You should print the tag at once: `<div></div>` and then append div's contents to it.

Comment: Yes, thanks for comment - I've changed to typer (it was my mistake).